# background image scaled and in center of container codenameone

Tags: codenameone

I am trying to use set the background of the container scaled and in center covering just some protion of the coontainer. When i use the normal image like below. It works fine but the image cover whole container.

```
Image img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeHolder, url, url, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE);
findContainerMain(f).setUIID("ContainerBgImage");
findContainerMain(f).getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED,true);
findContainerMain(f).getStyle().setBgImage(img, true);
```

But when i use scaled image as background then it doesnot show any image just white background.

```
Image img = URLImage.createToStorage(placeHolder, url, url, URLImage.RESIZE_SCALE).scaledHeight(50);
findContainerMain(f).setUIID("ContainerBgImage");
findContainerMain(f).getStyle().setBackgroundType(Style.BACKGROUND_IMAGE_SCALED,true);
findContainerMain(f).getStyle().setBgImage(img, true);
```

How can i obtain the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

A [URLImage](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/URLImage.html) is fetched lazily and relies on the animation properties of the image to update itself.

The `scaled` method creates a completely new image object which doesn't have the fetching properties associated with the `URLImage`.

Comment: I tries `Util.downloadUrlToStorageInBackground but the scaled image still fits in the container and is blurry. Anyway I can achieve the above mentioned design?

Comment: You didn't mention a design. You were very vague. I think that you don't need scaled or anything like that. Just scale_to_fit in the background behavior, or maybe center or maybe scale_to_fill. I didn't understand what you are trying to accomplish.